# Permanent HTML Video Control s(no fade out)

Tags: html, video

I'm using the HTML 5 video tag with the controls attribute. However when the user moves their mouse away from the video the controls disappear, how can I make it so they are constant?

Comment: @subbul the link you sent me has the answer to why your answer would never work "controls is a boolean attribute:

Note: The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether."

Comment: yup you are right, so you can keep controls=true, did that help?

Comment: @subbul no because it doesn't work, you either have <video controls> or <video> you don't do true or false, it has no effect!

Comment: you will need to create your own controls overlay. the default behavior for most browsers is to have the controls auto-hide